# Sinónimo [etiquetas] ← [tags] en Meta

Tags: soporte, sinónimos-de-etiquetas, meta

#### Estoy proponiendo [etiquetas](/questions/tagged/etiquetas) ← [tags](/questions/tagged/tags)

Sinónimo sugerido para Meta en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/etiquetas/synonyms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En esta semana, el jueves 18 de Mayo del 2017, he aprobado tu sugerencia, ahora son sinónimos.

> [etiquetas](/questions/tagged/etiquetas) (etiqueta maestra) - [tags](/questions/tagged/tags)

Comment: Sinónimos de etiqueta etiquetas :-)