# En Meta, sinónimos "no está funcionando" con las etiquetas predefinidas

Tags: soporte, sinónimos-de-etiquetas, meta

En [Privilegios - crear sinónimos de etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) y otras partes se indica que los sinónimos tienen la finalidad de evitar el tener que reetiquetar y que se sustituyen las los sinónimos por la etiqueta maestra.

En [respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63019/289691) (gracias Fedorqui), con fecha del 2010, se listas las etiquetas predefinidas para todos los sitios de Stack Exchange. Varias de estas etiquetas ya han sido marcadas como sinónimos de etiquetas en español, sin embargo, siguen estando disponibles y lo que es peor, al buscar la etiqueta maestra, no le incluyen las preguntas con los sinónimos.

A continuación, algunos ejemplos de solicitudes de sinónimos, los cuales ya fueron aplicados, pero no se ha obtenido el resultado esperado, evitar que aparezca en la sugerencia de etiquetas y reemplazar los sinónimos por la etiqueta maestra.

- [Hacer [burninate-request] sinónimo de [solicitud-de-quemado]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1731/65)
- [Hagamos [editing] sinónimo de [ediciones]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1743/65)
- [Sinónimo [etiquetas] ← [tags] en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1750/65)

Comment: Ojo: [meta-tag:editing] y [meta-tag:burninate-request] no se han marcado como sinónimos de etiquetas en español, como tampoco [meta-tag:formatting] (visto en [sinónimos de etiquetas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms)). Hasta que no reciba 4 votos positivos no será efectiva, por lo que el comportamiento es el correcto. Necesitamos o bien los votos de cuatro usuarios o el de un moderador.

Comment: De hecho decir que no está funcionando está mal, lo que pasa es que están pendientes.

Comment: Exacto: simplemente están pendientes

Comment: Supongo que habrá que esperar a que tengamos moderadores diamantados electos.

Comment: Sí, es una pena que el proceso de aceptar sinónimos tarde tantísimo, cuando con un moderador es inmediato.

Comment: Al ser etiquetas nuevas en muchos casos, justamente se publicó en meta para tener la discusión, pero el objetivo *era* que un moderador lo apruebe... En los casos que se pudo, se generó la votación de sinónimo para que sean sólo 2 clicks para un moderador.. Por eso las publicaciones están etiquetadas como [meta-tag:soporte]

Comment: @Mariano: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new

Comment: Perdón, me distraje, el enlace previo corresponde a la lista "oficial" de las etiquetas nuevas. No están ahí ninguno de los tres casos incluídos en la pregunta, pero si está [meta-tag:formato], que aunque no puse el ejemplo, está entre los casos que "barrí"

Comment: @Rubén "nuevas" en el sentido de que no estaban siendo utilizadas, sino que se utilizaba la etiqueta en inglés como aceptada, y que se propusieron los sinónimos, pero que no hay suficientes usuarios con reputación para aprobarlos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En esta semana, el jueves 18 de Mayo del 2017, he aprobado esas 5 sugerencias, ahora son sinónimos.

> Las de la izquierda son etiquetas maestras, mientras que las de la derecha son los sinónimos.
>
> - [ediciones](/questions/tagged/ediciones) ← [editing](/questions/tagged/editing) @fedorqui - [Hagamos [editing] sinónimo de [ediciones]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1743)
> - [solicitud-de-quemado](/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-quemado) ← [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) Tú y @Mariano - [Hacer [burninate-request] sinónimo de [solicitud-de-quemado]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1731)
> - [etiquetas](/questions/tagged/etiquetas) ← [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) @Mariano - [Sinónimo [etiquetas] ← [tags] en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1750)
> - [formato](/questions/tagged/formato) ← [formatting](/questions/tagged/formatting) y [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown) @Mariano -
>   [Sinónimos de [formato] en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1769)

Answer (score 2):

No es que esté funcionando mal. Lo que pasa es que están pendientes.

Véase una captura de pantalla de la página de [Sinónimos de etiqueta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms):

[image: Sinónimos de etiqueta pendientes]