# Traduzcamos toda la lista de etiquetas predeterminadas

Tags: característica-nueva, estado-completado, etiquetas, traducciones, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

En [Add a selection of default tags to all metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63019/209901) se define la lista de etiquetas predeterminadas de todo sitio Meta. Por tanto, es cuestión de coger esa lista y marcarla como sinónimo de su correspondiente en español.

Propongo poner la lista como respuesta wiki para ir tachando las que ya estén marcadas como sinónimas.

Nótese que Mariano, Rubén y más gente han ido proponiendo sinónimos en otras preguntas y eso ya ha permitido que algunos sinónimos se hayan creado. Con esta pregunta pretendo conseguir ser exhaustivo, ahora que finalmente descubrí la lista completa de las etiquetas predeterminadas. Todo esto surge a raíz de [¿Por qué hay tantas etiquetas en inglés?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1552/83)

---

Ayer no fui claro al definir el proyecto. Lo siento. Crear un sinónimo de etiqueta es un proceso muy tedioso utilizando las reglas actuales: se necesita que los usuarios voten y solo pueden hacerlo los que tienen cierta reputación en la etiqueta. Básicamente, impracticable para la mayoría de estos casos.

**Sin embargo**, para un moderador dicha creación de sinónimos es trivial: No se necesita que exista ninguna de las etiquetas (ni la original ni la sinónima). Por tanto, **no hace falta que creéis ninguna etiqueta**, especialmente las de versión inglesa. Incluyamos orgánicamente las de versión española allí donde hagan falta.

El objetivo pues de esta pregunta-respuesta es listar todas las etiquetas predefinidas y consensuar entre todos la mejor traducción para cada una de ellas.

Ruego pues lo siguiente: **revisad el listado y sugerid en los comentarios, o editando directamente, la versión que mejor exprese el concepto en castellano.**

Cuando hayamos llegado al consenso marcaré la pregunta como "característica-nueva" o "soporte". Así, cuando un moderador electo encuentre un momentito podrá marcar todos estos sinónimos de forma rápida e indolora.

Gracias y perdonad por no ser lo suficientemente explicativo en un principio :-)

Comment: No conocía la lista hasta que la nombraste hace poco. Creo que esta propuesta es totalmente necesaria. No hay otra forma de eliminar esas etiquetas en inglés.

Comment: Recientemente no se ha creado sinónimos, lo que se ha creado son  propuestas de sinónimos, el cual es el primer paso. La mayoría de estas no tienen ningún voto y mientras no se logren los votos requeridos, la creación de los sinónimos no se concluye.

Comment: Me parece que debería agregarse a [Jornada de Limpieza](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1828/65) por lo que he movido la respuesta que originalmente agregué aquí para allá.

Comment: @Rubén después de ver la que he "liado", creo que es mejor dejar simplemente una lista con la propuesta de traducciones y esperar a que un moderador los marque manualmente. Para ellos es trivial, un momentito (he hecho pruebas en [meta.spanish.se] ahora mismo). Es mucho más práctico que ir buscando votos en un proceso larguísimo. Por tanto, he editado la pregunta para reorientarla y así evitar que la tarea se nos vuelva tan grande. ¿Os parece?

Comment: Yo creo que una forma no cancela la otra en particular porque hay cosas inciertas, por ejemplo, aún no se dice cuándo y cómo se van a llevar a cabo las elecciones, así que no sabemos si habrá un moderador dispuesto, por otro lado está el caso `etiquette` y posible otras que requieran un tratamiento especial

Comment: @Rubén sí, evidentemente todo lo que podamos hacer la comunidad por nuestra cuenta será bienvenido. Mi punto es no invertir muchísimo tiempo en esto si luego un moderador puede hacerlo con mucha rapidez.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ### Se han hecho los correspondientes sinónimos de acuerdo a la siguiente propuesta:

#### Esta lista detalla las etiquetas predefinidas. A su derecha se encuentra la propuesta de traducción. El objetivo es consensuar esa traducción para que después un moderador pueda crear el sinónimo.

Por tanto, edita la lista con sugerencias de nombre más apropiado cuando veas uno que no te convence.

- [reputation](/questions/tagged/reputation) → [reputación](/questions/tagged/reputaci%c3%b3n)
- [questions](/questions/tagged/questions) → [preguntas](/questions/tagged/preguntas)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/preguntas/synonyms
- [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) → [etiquetas](/questions/tagged/etiquetas)

  - [Sinónimo [etiquetas] ← [tags] en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1750/127)
- [comments](/questions/tagged/comments) → [comentarios](/questions/tagged/comentarios)
- [badges](/questions/tagged/badges) → [medallas](/questions/tagged/medallas)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/medallas/synonyms
- [answers](/questions/tagged/answers) → [respuestas](/questions/tagged/respuestas)
- [search](/questions/tagged/search) → [búsqueda](/questions/tagged/b%c3%basqueda)
- [voting](/questions/tagged/voting) → [votos](/questions/tagged/votos)
- [editing](/questions/tagged/editing) → [ediciones](/questions/tagged/ediciones)

  - [Hagamos [editing] sinónimo de [ediciones]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1743/127)
- [bounty](/questions/tagged/bounty) → [recompensas](/questions/tagged/recompensas)
- [user-interface](/questions/tagged/user-interface) → [interfaz-de-usuario](/questions/tagged/interfaz-de-usuario)
- [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) → [revisión-de-pregunta](/questions/tagged/revisi%c3%b3n-de-pregunta)
- [accepted-answer](/questions/tagged/accepted-answer) → [respuesta-aceptada](/questions/tagged/respuesta-aceptada)
- [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown) → [formato](/questions/tagged/formato)

  - [Sinónimos de [formato] en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1769/83)
- [stackexchange](/questions/tagged/stackexchange) = [stackexchange](/questions/tagged/stackexchange) =
- [community-wiki](/questions/tagged/community-wiki) → [wiki-de-comunidad](/questions/tagged/wiki-de-comunidad)

  - [Sinónimo [wiki-de-comunidad] ← [community-wiki] en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1774/127)
- [down-votes](/questions/tagged/down-votes) → [votos-negativos](/questions/tagged/votos-negativos)
- [openid](/questions/tagged/openid) = [openid](/questions/tagged/openid) =
- [migration](/questions/tagged/migration) → [migración](/questions/tagged/migraci%c3%b3n)
- [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close) → [votos-de-cierre](/questions/tagged/votos-de-cierre)
- [exact-duplicates](/questions/tagged/exact-duplicates) → [duplicados-exactos](/questions/tagged/duplicados-exactos)

  - [Sinónimo [duplicados-exactos] ← [exact-duplicates] en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1778/83)
- [etiquette](/questions/tagged/etiquette) → [etiqueta](/questions/tagged/etiqueta) ? confuso ... [comportamiento-esperado](/questions/tagged/comportamiento-esperado) ? [netiqueta](/questions/tagged/netiqueta) ? [buenas-maneras](/questions/tagged/buenas-maneras) ? propuesta: [convenciones-sociales](/questions/tagged/convenciones-sociales)
- [notifications](/questions/tagged/notifications) → [notificaciones](/questions/tagged/notificaciones)
- [users](/questions/tagged/users) → [usuarios](/questions/tagged/usuarios)
- [closed-questions](/questions/tagged/closed-questions) → [cierre-de-preguntas](/questions/tagged/cierre-de-preguntas)
- [hyperlinks](/questions/tagged/hyperlinks) → [enlaces](/questions/tagged/enlaces)
- [data-dump](/questions/tagged/data-dump) → [volcado-de-información](/questions/tagged/volcado-de-informaci%c3%b3n)
- [asking-questions](/questions/tagged/asking-questions) → [formulado-de-preguntas](/questions/tagged/formulado-de-preguntas)
- [delete](/questions/tagged/delete) → [eliminación](/questions/tagged/eliminaci%c3%b3n)
- [recent-activity](/questions/tagged/recent-activity) → [actividad-reciente](/questions/tagged/actividad-reciente)
- [new-users](/questions/tagged/new-users) → [usuarios-nuevos](/questions/tagged/usuarios-nuevos)
- [profile-page](/questions/tagged/profile-page) → [perfil](/questions/tagged/perfil)
- [flagging](/questions/tagged/flagging) → [reportes](/questions/tagged/reportes)
- [chat](/questions/tagged/chat) = [chat](/questions/tagged/chat) =
- [unanswered-questions](/questions/tagged/unanswered-questions) → [preguntas-no-contestadas](/questions/tagged/preguntas-no-contestadas)
- [retagging](/questions/tagged/retagging) → [reetiquetado](/questions/tagged/reetiquetado)
- [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation) → [moderación](/questions/tagged/moderaci%c3%b3n)
- [data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer) = [data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer) =
- [close-reasons](/questions/tagged/close-reasons) → [motivos-de-cierre](/questions/tagged/motivos-de-cierre)
- [user-accounts](/questions/tagged/user-accounts) → [cuentas-de-usuario](/questions/tagged/cuentas-de-usuario)
- [formatting](/questions/tagged/formatting) → [formato](/questions/tagged/formato)

  - [Sinónimos de [formato] en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1769/83)
- [interesting-tags](/questions/tagged/interesting-tags) → [etiquetas-favoritas](/questions/tagged/etiquetas-favoritas)
- [up-votes](/questions/tagged/up-votes) → [votos-positivos](/questions/tagged/votos-positivos)
- [meta](/questions/tagged/meta) = [meta](/questions/tagged/meta) =
- [statistics](/questions/tagged/statistics) → [estadísticas](/questions/tagged/estad%c3%adsticas)
- [login](/questions/tagged/login) → [login](/questions/tagged/login) =
- [rss](/questions/tagged/rss) = [rss](/questions/tagged/rss) =
- [favorites](/questions/tagged/favorites) → [favoritos](/questions/tagged/favoritos)
- [deleted-questions](/questions/tagged/deleted-questions) → [eliminación-de-preguntas](/questions/tagged/eliminaci%c3%b3n-de-preguntas)
- [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) → [etiquetas](/questions/tagged/etiquetas)
- [votes](/questions/tagged/votes) → [votos](/questions/tagged/votos)

  - [Hagamos [votes] sinónimo de [votos]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1889/65)
- [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms) → [sinonimos-de-etiquetas](/questions/tagged/sinonimos-de-etiquetas) → [sinónimos-de-etiquetas](/questions/tagged/sin%c3%b3nimos-de-etiquetas) (con tilde)

  - Otro.
- [design](/questions/tagged/design) → [diseño](/questions/tagged/dise%c3%b1o) (Según un reporte de @fedorqui)

Comment: ¿Cómo sugieres que discutamos sobre casos como [meta-tag:etiquette] → [meta-tag:etiqueta]? Por ejemplo, propongo que usemos [meta-tag:código-de-conducta].

Comment: No pude crear el sinónimo de votes → votos porque no existe en el votes, pero si está listado en las etiquetas del sitio O_O

Comment: #explainlikeimfive Qué es exactamente lo que tengo que hacer?

Comment: @toledano añadí una explicación en la pregunta. Ayer no había sido suficientemente claro, disculpadme.

Comment: @Rubén no hace falta crear ninguna etiqueta. Simplemente definamos la mejor traducción y luego un moderador hará el mapeado.

Comment: @Rubén por cierto, sugiero recuperar la tilde en [meta-tag:sinónimos-de-etiquetas].

Comment: @fedorqui: sinonimos-de-etiqueta  ya existe pero sinónimos-de-etiquetas no. En cualquier caso, estoy de acuerdo en que se use la versión con acento.

Comment: @fedorqui Listo, ya he creado los sinónimos.

Comment: @ArtEze sos 　 　 muy 　 　 groso!

Comment: @ArtEze ¡eres una máquina!