# Hagamos [votes] sinónimo de [votos]

Tags: soporte, sinónimos-de-etiquetas, votos

En [Traduzcamos toda la lista de etiquetas predeterminadas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1887/65) se propone traducir todas las etiquetas predeterminadas. Esta tiene la finalidad de tener al menos una pregunta con la etiqueta [votes] para poder crear el sinónimo.

Enlace para ver los sinónimos de [votos]

https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/votos/synonyms

Comment: Sugeriría incluir a [meta-tag:voting] (también es una etiqueta predeterminada) como sinónimo de [meta-tag:votos].

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Traduzcamos toda la lista de etiquetas predeterminadas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1887/traduzcamos-toda-la-lista-de-etiquetas-predeterminadas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En esta semana, el jueves 18 de Mayo del 2017, he aprobado tu sugerencia, y he creado otra, por el comentario de @Mariano, ahora son sinónimos.

> [votos](/questions/tagged/votos) ← [votes](/questions/tagged/votes) *Esta pregunta* y [voting](/questions/tagged/voting) *El comentario de @Mariano*