# ¿Qué hacer con la descripción de la etiqueta buenas-practicas?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

He usado en varias preguntas la etiqueta [buenas-practicas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buenas-practicas), pero resulta que no tiene ninguna descripción ni nada.

Dado que es una etiqueta algo particular, ¿qué se podría poner en ella, para que no permanezca en blanco?

¿O consideran que no es tan necesario que esa etiqueta tenga alguna descripción?

Comment: Antes de nada, habría que añadirle una tilde a _prácticas_ :)

Comment: @fedorqui asumía que sin tilde iba bien, por tratarse de una etiqueta. ¿Influencia del inglés? La verdad es que en mi caso, no uso tildes en nombres de variables o de tablas o columnas, por eso pensaba que lo de la tilde aquí no era tan importante.

Comment: Ya que la página permite las tildes en las etiquetas, creo que es bueno usarlas. Así obramos por ejemplo al [Traducir toda la lista de etiquetas predeterminadas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1888/83). Eso sí, comparto totalmente el no usarlas en nombres de variables o tablas o columnas: cuando me he encontrado con ellas siempre han provocado problemas pues los lenguajes no suelen estar preparados para trabajar con otra cosa que las letras "normales".

Comment: Yo pondría alguna descripción del tipo `Usar la etiqueta, para consejos o preguntas sobre la manera mas uniforme de programar`

Comment: Es una gran candidata a ser baneada y eliminada.. Buenas practicas basados en que? un libro? un paper? salvo que haya un standar consensuado, las buenas practicas las da el entorno de trabajo y el equipo con el cual se trabaja. Esta etiqueta no deberia existir ademas, porque es una meta etiqueta. Depende siempre de otra y siempre hay que dar un entorno. Y asi y todo, la mayoria (no todas) de las respuestas son refutables por parte de otro equipo que trabaja diferente.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo contigo @gbianchi, las buenas prácticas existen y son tan concretas como cualquier otra cosa. Te plantearé un problema  y me dirás si hay una buena práctica para resolverlo: *Hay que seleccionar a 5 empleados entre 100 para un proyecto. Todos viven en Australia y la selección se puede hacer en cualquier sitio. Se puede hacer de 2 formas: a. Traer a los 100 y seleccionar; b. Ir a Australia y seleccionar a los 5 y entonces traerlos*. ¿Cuál es la buena práctica, a nivel económico, sabiendo que la empresa tiene que costear los pasajes aéreos y la estadía?

Comment: hablemos de sistemas.. yo te diria que la buena practica ahi es setear un skype por turnos ;)

Comment: @gbianchi la selección por skype podría ser la peor, el candidato podría usar artimañas para engañarte y no te darías cuenta :)

Comment: totalmente.. entonces? de que manual o bajo que estandar estaria basada la mejor practica? o sea.. es todo circunstancial.. por eso digo, la mejor practica es aquella que lleva al mejor resultado.. y podemos tener puntos de vista respecto de eso en equipos de trabajo en sistema.. la mejor practica es escribir las variables en ingles o español?

Comment: @gbianchi las preguntas con esa etiqueta suelen (o deberían basarse en datos concretos). Si por ejemplo, se pregunta por dos o tres métodos alternativos para hacer algo, cuál es la mejor práctica en cuanto al rendimiento... y hasta caben algunos matices. En este contexto esta es mejor práctica, y en este otro esta práctica es mejor. La programación está llena de casos de esos, pero no son millones de casos, sino dos o tres a lo sumo. Por ejemplo en PDO, `fetchAll` no es bueno si se esperan muchos resultados... es mejor leer los resultados iterando sobre ellos en un bucle.

Comment: Entonces despues de todo esto ya tenes una descripcion para la etiqueta ;)

Comment: Se pregunta para obtener respuestas en base a datos medibles. Por ejemplo [aquí](https://jsperf.com/array-tostring-vs-array-join), se pueden comparar tres métodos y decidir en base a esos datos cuál es la mejor práctica. Los llamados *benchmark*  son parte de la informática.

Answer (score 5):

Quiero pensar que [buenas-practicas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buenas-practicas) no es [rendimiento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rendimiento), y que no debería usarse para referirse a benchmarks o para evaluar eficiencia.

Entiendo que son cuestiones de implicancias a futuro sobre un método u otro para resolver un problema x, si conviene de tal forma porque eso facilitará el mantenimiento/update, etc.
Pero **no** para evaluar si un código corre más rápido que otro.

Personalmente, me parece algo cercana una meta-etiqueta (que no me imagino usando). Pero creo que está/estaría bien aplicada a estas preguntas:

- [¿Es válido usar break en estructuras de control repetitivas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/125903/127)
- [¿Por qué el uso de + en las librerías gradle de Android es una mala práctica?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/120790/127)
- [¿Cuál es la convención para escribir variables en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/78420/127)
- [Escribir código PHP multi plataforma (sistemas operativos)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/111912/127)
- [Uso de Ñ en nombre de variables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/22360/127)

Y creo que el factor común en estas preguntas es "**cómo evitar malas prácticas**" (código funcional que puede resultar perjudicial en otra circunstancia).

Asimismo, me parece mal aplicada en:

- [DATE() vs DATE_FORMAT() en MySQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/112168/127)
- [¿Como configurar las carpetas de sincronizacion en Qnap y NAS?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/110787/127)
- [Es una buena práctica devolver referencias a un array o se debe modificar el propio array](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/131122/127)

Sólo [3 usuarios la usaron hasta ahora](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/buenas-practicas/topusers), con un claro ganador, por lo que creo que estás más que en condiciones de agregar información relevante en la wiki de la etiqueta. No te olvides de leer [Aprobación de wikis de etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) y de incluir la orientación de uso (cuándo usar esa etiqueta, cuándo no, y qué otras etiquetas debería agregar en la misma pregunta).